# Do not define constants this way within a block. When defining class within a block

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubocop

Im defining a class within the routes block to handle ajax stuff

```
#config/routes.rb
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  class OnlyAjaxRequest
     def matches?(request)
       request.xhr?
     end
  end
#rest of the routes
end
```

However I get this warning in the editor:

```
Do not define constants this way within a block.Lint/ConstantDefinitionInBlock(RuboCop)
```

it seems this is a bad practice, but Im not sure how I can fix it, any ideas?

Comment: Did you look it up on Rubocop? https://msp-greg.github.io/rubocop/RuboCop/Cop/Lint/ConstantDefinitionInBlock.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the [docs](https://docs.rubocop.org/rubocop/1.2/cops_lint.html#lintconstantdefinitioninblock):

> Do not define constants within a block, since the block’s scope does not isolate or namespace the constant in any way.
>
> If you are trying to define that constant once, define it outside of the block instead, or use a variable or method if defining the constant in the outer scope would be problematic.

You can define the `OnlyAjaxRequest` class outside the block to fix the issue.

```
class OnlyAjaxRequest
  def matches?(request)
    request.xhr?
  end
end

Rails.application.routes.draw do
  # ...
end
```

---

Since the constraint is really simple, you don't even need to create a class. You can pass a lambda to the `constraints` option.

```
is_ajax_request = ->(request) { request.xhr? }

get '/some_route', to: 'test#action', constraints: is_ajax_request
```

Comment: Thanks for the extra tip, I actually think passing a lambda is more appropiate.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see why you want to define a class inside the block in your concrete case, since you can it define equally well outsie, but in case you ever come accross a situation where you really want to do it locally, you can do it as

```
 Object.const_set(
   "OnlyAjayRequest", 
     Class.new { 
       def matches?(request) 
         request.xhr?
       end 
     }
 )
```

Comment: Thanks, I just lack of resources for some ruby things, but I totally agree with you, always happy to learn new stuff, thank you